# dynamically passing variable from jinja variable

Tags: python, ajax, flask, jinja2

I am trying to pass a jinja variable in ajax call.i am calling the gerSlots routes. I want the URL to post to /getAppointments/.But its printing the {{ userName }}

```
@app.route('/getAppointments/<userName>', methods=['POST'])
def getSlots(userName):
    requestedDate=request.get_json() 
    print(userName)
    print(requestedDate)
    return redirect(url_for('appointments',rDate=requestedDate,userName=userName))  

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ url_for('getSlots',userName= '{{ userName }}')}}",
        data: JSON.stringify(date.format()) ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple fix 
Remove the `{{ }}` form username. 
You are using the `username` jinja variable in a jinja `url_for` method. that means that you can use `username` without the `{{ }}`